# Android reboots when I try to set a service foreground

Tags: android, service, reboot, foreground, cyanogenmod

I've hit a strange behaviour in my app: when I try to set a service foreground, the handset (HTC G1 + Cyanogen Mod) reboots.

It works when I don't try to foreground this service.

Here is the incriminated code:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
    getText(R.string.ticker_text), System.currentTimeMillis());
    startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
Log.v(TAG, "Control service foregrounded.");
```

Can you see where is the problem?

If you need more data, the whole project can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/rbochet/Serval-Video-Discovery/tree/network-remote

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this Android API Demo [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ForegroundService.html). Notice that rather than calling `startForeground()`, it calls `startForegroundCompat()`, a wrapper that handles your request depending on the new/old startForeground API.

```
void handleCommand(Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_FOREGROUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            ...

            // Set the icon, scrolling text and timestamp
            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.stat_sample, text,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this notification
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, Controller.class), 0);

            // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.local_service_label),
                           text, contentIntent);

            startForegroundCompat(R.string.foreground_service_started, notification);
            ...
    }
```

Here is `startForegroundCompat()`:

```
/**
 * This is a wrapper around the new startForeground method, using the older
 * APIs if it is not available.
 */
void startForegroundCompat(int id, Notification notification) {
    // If we have the new startForeground API, then use it.
    if (mStartForeground != null) {
        mStartForegroundArgs[0] = Integer.valueOf(id);
        mStartForegroundArgs[1] = notification;
        invokeMethod(mStartForeground, mStartForegroundArgs);
        return;
    }

    // Fall back on the old API.
    mSetForegroundArgs[0] = Boolean.TRUE;
    invokeMethod(mSetForeground, mSetForegroundArgs);
    mNM.notify(id, notification);
}
```